# How to remove white space between the tabs in react navigation top bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

How do you remove white space between the tabs in react-navigation top bar. So what should happen is the tab size should adjust based on the screen size.

This is what my navigation looks like at the moment.

[image]

You can see that the tabs are really big. They are taking too much space. How can I get those white spaces so the tabs are only taking enough size to fit the tab name.

I've tried styling `Tab.Navigator` with no luck. For example Ive tried the following:

```
<Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="All"
      tabBarOptions={{
        scrollEnabled: true,
        labelStyle: { padding: 0, margin: 0, border: 0 },
        tabStyle: { padding: 0, margin: 0, border: 0 },
      }}
      lazy={true}
      style={{ padding: 0, margin: 0, border: 0 }}
    >
```

```
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs";

import Home from "../screens/Home";

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const HomeTabNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="All"
      tabBarOptions={{
        scrollEnabled: true,
        labelStyle: { padding: 0, margin: 0, border: 0 },
        tabStyle: { padding: 0, margin: 0, border: 0 },
      }}
      lazy={true}
      style={{ padding: 0, margin: 0, border: 0 }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="All" component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Hot" component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Winners" component={Home} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const HomeNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="HomeTabNavigation" component={HomeTabNavigation} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default HomeNavigation;
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem just a couple of days ago.

Here is my solution for you:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useWindowDimensions } from "react-native"; // <-- add this hook
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs";

import Home from "../screens/Home";

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const tabsConfig = () => {
    const { width } = useWindowDimensions()
    return {
        lazy: true,
        tabBarOptions: {
            showLabel: true,
            tabStyle: {
                // here you can set the tab width , in this case , 3 tabs , width / 3
                width: width / 3,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                alignSelf: 'center',
            },
            indicatorStyle: {
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: 'red',
            }
        },
    }
}

const HomeTabNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator {...tabsConfig()}>
      <Tab.Screen name="All" component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Hot" component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Winners" component={Home} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const HomeNavigation = () => {
  return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="HomeTabNavigation" component={HomeTabNavigation} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default HomeNavigation;
```

Comment: Only setting the `width` property will still leave large amount of space between. Set `marginHorizontal` to negative value to fully get rid of the spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Set width to auto like this:

```
screenOptions={{
   tabBarItemStyle: {width: "auto"}
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the height by simply using :

```
<Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="All"
      tabBarOptions={{
        style: {
          height: 40,
       }
      }}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make shadowOffset and elevation as 0 in the homeTabNavigator style

Comment: please, explain better why do you say that

Comment: By default in react navigation, the shadowOffset Or elevation value is not zero. That means it will give some shadows. To remove that we are making them as zero. (Note: shadowOffset is used in ios for shadows.. In Android we can achieve that with the help of elevation)